# Functions from native .so library, SIGSEGV error [Android]

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I call native methods of .so library from my Java code, I receive Fatal signal 11 SIGSEGV error, and crash of my app.

What's the problem might be with this function? Thanks in advance

Comment: Quite likely a bad type conversion / function prototype mismatch between native and java, or static/non-static mismatch, but without your code we can only speculate.  Reduce you case to the shortest function which causes this crash, and post that code (both native and the corresponding native method declaration in java).  Or start with the hello jni sample from the ndk samples directory, get that work, and modify it to be the same as your app, taking note of where it fails.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for reply, I'll try to find out the mismatch.

Comment: you should use ndk-stack.exe with dump from this sigseg (which is located in logcat), this will show you stack trace to location where problem is.

Comment: @marcinj in general when I find out the problem is with the .so lib. What is at hand that I can do to resolve it? I am in a similar kind of tight fix, where the problem is with the lib?